# why does this .append only append the even numbered strings?

Tags: python-3.x, append

```
guest_list = []
while input() != '.':
    guest = input()
    guest_list.append(guest)
print(f'{guest_list}\n{len(guest_list)}')
```

why does this code only append the even numbered guests?
for example, if I input the names: Katja - Adam - Eva - Nicholas - .

the print will be:

`['Adam', 'Nicholas'] \n 2`

also, how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Your check `while input()` eats half of your names:

> ```
> guest_list = []
> while input() != '.':       # THIS input is not added to the list.
>     guest = input()
>     guest_list.append(guest)
> print(f'{guest_list}\n{len(guest_list)}')
> ```

Fix:

```
guest_list = []
while not guest_list or guest_list[-1] != '.':
    guest = input()
    guest_list.append(guest)

guest_list[:] = guest_list [:-1]
print(f'{guest_list}\n{len(guest_list)}')
```

Even better:

```
guest_list = []
while True:
    guest = input()
    if guest == '.':
        break
    guest_list.append(guest)

print(f'{guest_list}\n{len(guest_list)}')
```

Comment: I don't thinks that's correct because, as soon as I start this program, it prints ```[ ] \n 0``` and closes

Comment: @Sebas - use the second version. Fixed the first.

Comment: thanks for the solution! one thing that's still unclear to me is why the ```while input()```"eats" half of my inputs. can someone explain please? –

Comment: @sebas Each `input()` consumes one input thats why: you enter the while - the test of the condition eats one inputted name. but you do not add it to your list. then you input another name, thats gets added, then back to while loop condition test.  again not added  etc.